# What is the differences between MVC3 and MVC4 in c# Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

What are the features introduced in MVC4 Architecture compared to MVC3 in ASP.net?

Comment: This is answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535327/difference-between-asp-net-mvc-3-and-4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Better check the below links to find out the differences.

[MVC3 and MVC4](http://forums.asp.net/t/1753017.aspx/1)

[Diff MVC3 and MVC4](http://www.askamoeba.com/Answer/130/Whats-new-in-MVC4-MVC3-Vs-MVC4)

[Official MVC4 release notes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes)