# Does Visual Studio 2010 support MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-5

My question is can we develop an application in Visual Studio 2010 using MVC 5?

If yes, please also mention the tutorial or sample code url with your answer.

If no, then please specify the requirements of MVC 5 to build an application with it?

Answer (score 32):

No it isn't possible. You need Visual Studio 2012 and I thought .NET 4.5 at least. See the upgrade notes for detail information http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Answer (score 13):

You need VS 2012 or above to have MVC5 support.

Answer (score 8):

From [the EF Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/08/15/ef5-released.aspx)

> **Compatibility**
>
> This version of the NuGet package is fully compatible with Visual
>   Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2012 and can be used for applications
>   targeting .NET 4.0 and 4.5.
>
> **Some features are only available when writing an application that
>   targets .NET 4.5**. This includes enum support, spatial data types,
>   table-valued functions and the performance improvements.

I was able to add EF5 to an MVC4 project through NuGet. You can certainly use [MVC 4](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Rowan-Miller-Demonstrates-Entity-Framework-5-Using-ASPNET-MVC-4), you just won't get all the new features unless you're on VS2012.

[Difference MVC3 VS MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535327/difference-between-asp-net-mvc-3-and-4)

Comment: Amit Thanks for your answer.....please suggest what MVC version better for me with Visual Studio 2010 either MVC 3 or MVC 4

Comment: If you are using WEBAPI then Use `VS 2012 with MVC4` else `MVC3` is good. Difference is in my answer

Comment: But the ask is about the MVC and that resposta if about EF... two different things